# File access permitions and rights

Tags: permissions, files

What will happen if I change the rights and file permissions in the / ( root ) folder for all system folders to 700? Is it recommendable?

( I am the only user on the system )

Comment: TL;DR, it would make your system unusable.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

`700` denies all access to users other than the superuser (eg root).

It would effectively deny anybody running an application as a normal user, or even logging in.  Applications (eg in `/usr`) and their configuration (in `/etc`) and data (in `/var`) need to be accessible by the user that is going to run those applications.

For any file that it is important to be inaccessible to regular users, that permission will already be set.  Do not try to re-invent the security features already built into the operating system.